# Example of the fact that outer measure is subadditive but not countably additive

Tags: measure-theory

I am looking for an explicit example of the fact that outer measure is sub-additive but not additive. Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
\mu(A)=\begin{cases}1& \text{ if } A \text{ infinite}\\
0&\text{ if } A \text{ finite}. 
\end{cases}
$$
for $A \subset \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Isn't for any Infinite subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ $\mu^*(A) = 0$ thus $\mu(A) = 0$?